# How to use MapDynamicControllerRoute to select a specific controller without the conventional controller routing in ASP.NET core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, routes

I want to decide where to send each url at runtime.
I don't want to use attributes like `[Route("/hello")]` and I don't want to use the conventional `[controller=hello]/[action=Index]`. What I want is a way to execute a specific controller after deciding with my own logic like this

```
if(context.Request.Path.Value == "/hello"){
   SomehowCallTheActionOnController("MyController", "MyAction", anyUrlValuesLikeId);
}
```

Using the `DynamicRouteValueTransformer`, I can get the dictionary of values such as `values["controller"]="home";` But since I want to catch all, in my case I only get `"values["all"]="hello/this/is/my/url"`, even if I set the controller name manually, it won't work because I don't want to use the conventional mapping of controllers and actions.

I guess what I'm trying to do is the equivalent of `Route::get('/user', [UserController::class, 'index']);` in laravel for example; use my own routing but let asp pass dependency injections to controllers and instantiate ActionContext for me. Is this possible at all in ASP.NET?

I can just use

```
app.MapGet("myroute", async context => {
    var actionContext = new ActionContext(context, context.getRouteData(), new ActionRequest());
    await new ContentResult(){ Content = "hi" }.ExecuteResultAsync(actionContext);
})
```

and manage dependency injections on my own by GetService... but I'm not sure this is how it's supposed to be done because the actionRequest for example won't have all necessary properties set up, and asp might be using it for something??

Anyway, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. When you specify the controller name for the route, you must not include the word "Controller"!

Like this:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
                "About",
                "/About/{something}",
                defaults: new { controller = "App", action = "Index" }
            );
```

and the controller name is "AppController" with a method "Index" like this

```
public class AppController : Controller {
        public IActionResult Index(string something) {
            return /* put your result here */;
        }
    }
```

I still don't know how to specify a method (GET, POST, etc) with "MapControllerRoute" but at least this way I can specify routes from an array with templates and names...